# Javascript Sticky nav scrollTo

Tags: javascript, header, sticky

so I got this sticky header that works great the only problem I have is when  I press a link and the screen scrolls down it overlaps my content so I need to set a -47px height or something like that so the # it scrolls to get below the menu and not under it.

My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var stickyNavTop = $('.header').offset().top;  

    var stickyNav = function(){  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
            $('.header').addClass('sticky');
        } else {  
            $('.header').addClass('sticky');   
        }  
    };  

    stickyNav();  

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();  
    });  
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });
        $(closenav).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 760 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
```

Sorry if i'm not clear enough and need to explain it in another way.
Please keep in mind I'm a JS rookie!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top -47
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

add this within your `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Close! It scrolls to the right place but 1 second after it goes down and covers content again.

Comment: can you provide a Link to your work or a jsfiddle .. the code i have submitted works for me.